Synchronizing dynamic parallelism in CDP2
Up until a few years ago, the following demonstrative CUDA code was perfectly workable:
__global__ void parent_kernel(int *output){

  int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  int Alice, Bob;
  float *Charly, *Dave;

  Alice = tid;
  for(int j=0; j<100; ++j){
    child_kernel1<<<1,512>>>(Charly);
    cudaThreadSynchronize();
    Alice=f(Alice,Charly);

    child_kernel2<<<1,512>>>(Dave);
    cudaThreadSynchronize();
    Bob=g(Alice,Dave);
  }
  output[tid] = Bob;
}


//Later...
parent_kernel<<<32,32>>>(Ellie);

The for-loop cannot be parallelized, because iteration j+1 depends on the result of j, with presumably some horribly nonlinear functions being called each time.
To process a pair of large arrays, some child kernels are called from the device. The calling thread needs each and every one of the threads executing the child kernels to finish before it can evaluate the functions f and g. An approach is used from this still-available article on the NVIDIA website.
However, as stated in the CUDA programming guide, this is deprectated. A developer said "Yes, this will require refactoring your code. There is no zero-impact workaround that I am aware of".
What is the new best practice with the most recent approach? Bear in mind that the example given is trivial; it could have any number of other functions, nested if-statements and a dynamic number of child kernel threads.
One could imagine something like the following; call the parent kernel with this
parent_kernel<<<1024,512>>>(Ellie);

Inside it, the child kernel calls would be done away with, and the 512 threads in the block used to do those calculations directly. I am wondering how best to approach this, however. Should every thread in the block evaluate the following line,
Alice=f(Alice,Charly);

or should the result be passed around using shared memory?

"Should every thread in the block evaluate the following line [...]?" That can't be answered without knowing what f() does/how expensive it is. There is no one-size fits all solution.

The reason for this feature being removed is that it was slow. Generally I would only use CDP for problems with data-dependent parallelism or similar, i.e. "a dynamic number of child kernel threads". In that case the CDP2 solution is to put f() and g() into further child kernels and use stream semantics for the synchronization. See CUDA C++ Programming Guide

@paleonix This seems unclear to me. It suggests that you can call do_nothing<<<1,1,0,cudaStreamTailLaunch>>>(); instead of the old cudaThreadSynchronize();. Why not just keep the latter as a wrapper for the former, then? And if this is inefficient, what is the recommended efficient solution?

Starting a child kernel and then synchronizing means that the parent kernel will potentially block resources (SMs etc) while doing nothing. Tail launching another kernel does not block resources.
